# Can I convert doc/docx into rtf/pdf on the fly, on the server?

Tags: c#, windows, pdf, ms-word, rtf

We run linux for our cluster on AWS, but I can set up a Windows machine if this is the most error-proof way of doing this, and write a simple web service to perform the conversion (if the answer to this question indicates it is possible to do this...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Word Automation Services](http://www.zimmergren.net/archive/2010/08/30/sp-2010-developing-with-the-word-automation-services-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx) in Sharepoint.

Comment: WAS isn't exactly what I'd call 'on the fly' conversion. It's a batch process, and only starts new batches at most every minute (though it can really churn through some documents when it gets going) and isn't well suited to single document generation. I think this was a serious oversight by MS, especially considering how nice the output is (flawless).